# ggplot - writing a function to create ggplot - how to assign parameter correctly?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I cannot find an answer to this simple problem:

I want to create a ggplot. The `aes` parameter come partially from vector and partially are assigned directly.

```
names(mydt)
"gender"     "cat1"        "category_b"    "value"


category_a <- "cat1"

plot.sum <- mydt %>%
  dplyr::group_by(category_a, category_b) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = category_a, y = N, fill = category_b)) +
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") 
plot.sum
```

This does not work and i get an error:

Error: Column `category_a` is unknown

I assume this is because R expects `category_a` to be a column in `mydt` and instead it gets an character item from a vector "cat1", which does not exist in `mydt` - correct me if i am wrong?

**How can this be fixed?**

The ultimate goal is to make this to a function:

```
make.plot.sum <- function (data, group_by1, group_by2, position){

data %>%
  dplyr::group_by(group_by1, group_by2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = group_by1, y = N, fill = group_by2)) +
    geom_bar(position="position", stat="identity") 
  plot.sum

  return(plot.sum)

}

make.plot.sum(mydt, category_a, category_b, stack)
```

Comment: Have you tried `aes(x = {{group_by1}}, y = N, fill = {{group_by2}})`?

Comment: @teunbrand  i am not sure what the {{}} stand for, buut it seems like eit converts the group_by1 t plain text, but it was originally a factor with about 15 levels

Comment: Alright and `aes(x = .data[[group_by1]], y = N, fill = .data[[group_by2]])`? I think the post on this piece of nonstandard evaluation can be found here: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/

Answer (score 1):

You are correct: the issue is likely due to passing a character `"cat1"` to `aes()`, when `aes()` expects you to pass a column name (i.e. `cat1` without any quotes).  If you want to pass info to `aes(...` as a character, you can use `aes_string(...)` in place of `aes()`:  just make sure that when you use `aes_string()`, all the parameters are character vectors, and for `aes()`, all parameters are references to column names in your dataframe.

*Side Note: I'm not actually sure if you can combine `aes()` and `aes_string(...)`, in case you are wondering... I've never tried it. So, like can you say `aes(x=cat1)`, then `aes_string(y='cat2')`?  Not sure.*

Answer (score 0):

`chemdorks123`s answer is a great one - but it is worth pointing out that `aes_string` is considered soft decrecated in favor of new idioms.

In your situation, where you want the user to pass a column into aes, you can use curly braces (`{{}}`).

```
make.plot.sum <- function (data, group_by1, group_by2, position){

data %>%
  dplyr::group_by(group_by1, group_by2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = {{group_by1}}, y = N, fill = {{group_by2}})) +
    geom_bar(position="position", stat="identity") 
  plot.sum

  return(plot.sum)

}
```

There's a lot more info in one of the `ggplot2` vignettes - [Using ggplot2 in packages](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html)

Comment: as i was just commenting to @teunbrand who proposed this solution (see above), this acts as if the factor `group_by1` had only one level, when it acttually has multiple leevels

Comment: Can you expand on what you expect the `group_by` to do? Its been a while since I've looked, but I dont think `ggplot2` understands groups created by dplyr. Does it work like you expect outside of the function? If you're wanting to create multiple plots based on a factor level, it would make more sense to pass the grouping into a facet

Comment: @Conoe Neilson it works fine, before when i use `cat1` instead of  instead of `category_a` in the plot. As soon as i use `category_a <- cat1` , i get the error.